# Updating UI With An Internet Access Every Time The Screen is Refreshed

Tags: android

I need to do an internet access to update a field on my UI.  I do the internet access in a background thread by extending AsyncTask.

Since I need to update my UI every time the screen is refreshed I am executing the AsyncTask in my onResume method:

@Override
protected void onResume(){
 super.onResume();

showDialog(REFRESH_DIALOG);
 new UpdateAgentStatusTask().execute();
}

I dismiss the REFRESH_DIALOG dialog in the onPostExecute() method in the AsyncTask.

For testing I rotate the screen to landscape.  Things work well.  The problem is when I try to rotate again to portrait.  I get 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 1 was ever shown ...'.  id 1 is for the REFRESH_DIALOG.

How do I get rid of this error?  Is there a better way to do an internet access to update my UI every time the screen is refreshed?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Answer (score 0):

cancel your asyncTask before leaving  using the onCancel() event in the AsyncTask. I don't know if you have to actually cancel the task yourself in the onPause() event for the main activity or if the onCancel() if fired by the OS during rotation.